# Syntax error(missing operator) in mysql query

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I am working on a project in which I need to export the record set of a query to an Excel file. I got the Excel export part working. But I am having some trouble with the query.

```vb
Private Sub Tch_rep_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

strSQL = "SELECT tbl_tch.teacher_id,teacherfirstname_vchr,teachersurname_vchr,description_vchr,teacheremail_vchr FROM tbl_tch " & _
"LEFT JOIN tbl_tchcareer ON tbl_tch.teacher_id = tbl_tchcareer.teacher_id " & _
"LEFT JOIN tbl_typedescription ON tbl_tchcareer.tchspecialism_int = tbl_typedescription.description_int " & _
"AND tbl_typedescription.descriptiongroup_int = 6 " & _
"ORDER BY tbl_tch.teacher_id DESC"

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("TeacherRecords", strSQL)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "TeacherRecords", "K:\Records\Teachers\Teacher Records.xls", True

CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete qdf.Name

qdf.Close
End Sub
```

I get the following error message.

> Syntax error(missing operator)in query expression
>   'tbl_tch.teacher_id=tbl_tchcareer.teacher_id left join
>   tbl_typedescription on
>   tbl_tchcareer.tchspecialism_int=tbl_typedescription.description_int

When I use a simple query like "`select * from tablename`" everything works.

The query works in mysql console.

Comment: Are you missing a `WHERE` ?

Comment: No actually when i use where instead of AND, it works fine. But it does not return all the records. only the current query returns all the records that i need

Comment: the query works fine in mysql workbench. Unfortunately not working in this context(vba)

Comment: Judging by the code it is probably not MySQL query, but MS Access query. SO you should test the query in MS Access (not Workbench) - I'd say that you need some brackets in FROM clause.